# Sails.js API passport.js authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I am trying to develop an API backend in Sails.js.

The most basic thing which I require is authentication.

With that, I found the `sails-generate-auth` generator, I have followed all the steps listed at 
[sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) .

Now, when I access `http://localhost:1337/register`, I see a simple registration form, same goes for login, and after logging in, I see a cookie set in my browser as `sails.sid`.

After inspecting the `AuthController.js` I see that it has been written for server rendered views.

How should I modify the controller/sailsApp so that it supports API based authentication.

I would ideally like to have:

1. A register route which would accept username and password via post
   with content type application/json.
2. Login route which would accept username and password with
   content-type application/json and return with a bearer token so that the frontend app can add it to its header the next time it makes a request.
3. All other routes under an auth ACL which would check if the bearer
   token is present and is verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AuthController callback function replace this:

```
res.redirect('/');
```

with this:

```
console.log(user);
var userID = user.id;
Passport.find({user: userID}, function(err, items){
    if(err) return err;

    console.log(items[0].accessToken);
    // Make sure you dont give them any sensetive data
    res.json({userData: user, token: items[0].accessToken});
});
// Upon successful login, send the user to the homepage were req.user
//res.redirect('/');
```

Now when the client sends a login/register request the server will response with a JSON response. Make sure you request the token on your other sails app actions.

Comment: Hey thank you. and Oh, that was pretty straight forward!

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using these steps for a while now.

Step 1 ( Globals ): $ npm install -g sails

Step 2 ( App ): $ sails new myApp

Step 3 ( Files ): Copy every file in https://github.com/carlospliego/sails-token-auth-setup to its corresponding folder

Step 4 ( Policies ): Add this code to your config/policies.js

```
 '*': "hasToken",
 UserController: {
    "create": true
 },
 AuthController: {
    '*': true
 }
```

Step 5: change the value of config/tokenSecret.js

Step 6: ( Dependencies )

- npm install --save passport
- npm install --save passport-local
- npm install --save bcrypt-nodejs
- npm install --save jsonwebtoken
- npm install --save express-jwt

---

Your endpoints will look like this:

- POST/GET/PUT/DELETE user/
- POST auth/login
- DELETE auth/logout

---

Here is a great guide on how to create token based authentication in sails: https://github.com/carlospliego/sails-token-auth-setup